# Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly [Loggin]

Tags: python

I am trying to save some informations and I get the error
"Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly” 
I was using str() instead of format but it showed the same error
Please help thx.

```
def save_model(json_string, dirpath='results/'):
    with open(dirpath + starttime +'.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json_string)

def save_config(config, dirpath='results/'):
    with open(dirpath + 'config_log.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(starttime + '\n')
        f.write((config) + '\n')

 def save_result(starttime, conv_arch, dense, train_acc, val_acc, dirpath='results/'):
     with open(dirpath + starttime +'_train_val.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write("{0}".format(train_acc) + '\n')
        f.write("{0}".format(val_acc) + '\n')

     endtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
     with open(dirpath + 'result_log.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(starttime + '--' + endtime + ' comment: ' + notes + '\n' )
        f.write("{0}".format(conv_arch) + ',{0}'.format(dense) + '\n')
        f.write('Train acc: {0}'.format(train_acc[-1]) +
            'Val acc: {0}'.format(val_acc[-1]) +
            'Ratio: {0}'.format(val_acc[-1]/train_acc[-1]) + '\n')
```

here is the output

```
     INFO - File "cnn6.py", line 109, in cnn_architecture
     INFO - dropout, X_shape, y_shape, train_acc, val_acc, dirpath)
     INFO - File "cnn6.py", line 33, in logging
     INFO - save_result(starttime, conv_arch, dense, train_acc, val_acc, now)
     INFO - File "/code/log.py", line 20, in save_result
     INFO - with open(dirpath + starttime +'_train_val.txt', 'w') as f:
     INFO - TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more description? Error message?

Comment: `train_acc = train_acc`? `val_acc = val_acc`?

Comment: I did not pat attention to these lines I changed the names of the save_result function and did not remove those two lines

Comment: It looks like `starttime`  is a float and not a string, unlike what you did with `endtime`.

Comment: f.write(str(starttime) + '--' + str(endtime))

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan  your comment solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is required to solve your problem.

```
    F.write(str(starttime)+str(endtime))
```

Reason is that your time is in float and you need to conacat it by converting to strings

Here is a basic [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-convert-data-types-in-python-3) to learn more about these topics.